# android date format: how to get the format from string

Tags: android, android-date, android-dateutils

I am getting this `14-03-2014 09:02:10` string from JSON. All is OK but I want just the date part in this string not the time `(14-03-2014)`. So how can I convert the string to this format.

Comment: What if you use a substring? Something like `date = date.substring(0,9);`

Comment: String[] string="14-03-2014 09:02:10".split(" "); 

String date=string[0];

Comment: Just ask another question. First try to find similar question. you can easily find alot similar question and there answer as well as ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the `String`, a `substring` would do the work:

```
date = date.substring(0,10);
```

Comment: substring(0,9), here 9 would clip last digit, plz confirm

Comment: Then, add one more! 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

You just try this solution i hope it will useful for you just give the date format into one you can get the desired one...

```
String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        String outputPattern = "dd/MM";
        SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
        Date date1 = null;

        if (date != null) {
            try {
                date1 = inFormat.parse(date);
                str = outputFormat.format(date1);
                Log.d(null, str);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            str = " ";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Split() method for extract date part from String

```
String str = "14-03-2014 09:02:10"
String [] part = str.split(" ");
String date = part[0];
```

Or you can also use `substring()` method if your date field's size is constant, i.e. for 01 instead of 1 in date part

```
str = str.substring(0,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` method

```
String jsonString = "14-03-2014 09:02:10";
if(jsonString.contains(" ")){
   String onlyDate = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" ")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        String date_time = "14-03-2014 09:02:10";
        String[] split_val = date_time.split(" ");
        String date = split_val[0];
        String time = split_val[1];
        System.out.println(date+"--------------"+time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
String date="14-03-2014 09:02:10";
String reqdate=date.substring(0,10);
```